# Catch key events in a NSWindow

Tags: objective-c, xcode, webkit, nswindow

I'm trying to get a very basic web browser with 3 Webviews (2 hidden and 1 visible at all times).

I'd like to switch between these 3 webviews by pressing CMD+1, CMD+2, CMD+3.

I have created a basic Cocoa app, added 3 webviews in it, referenced the Webkit framework and I'm up and running with it, this part is working.

Now I wonder:

**1) How to catch key event?** It seems so overly complicated that browsing the event structure docs gave me a headache.

[rant]From someone who did lots of Windows forms, GTK, QT and Java/C#/C++ work it seems that XCode is getting worse every release by moving everything around and creating 3 different ways of achieving the same thing, etc. Each time I have to use it's always like I have to learn everything once again.[/rant]

**2) How to specifically catch CMD+NUMBERS ?**

This is just for a quick productivity app I'm building to use in conjunction with JIRA (project management).

I'd appreciate if somebody could point me in the good direction.

Every time I stumble upon a good tutorial, it was outdated or was for iOS dev which most of the time doesn't use the same APIs as OS X anymore.

Sorry about the rant and thanks about your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking to override is the [NSResponder method "`keyDown:`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/keyDown%3a), and what I would recommend doing is subclassing "`WebView`" and create your own "`keyDown`" method (make certain to call "`[super keyDown: theEvent]`" somewhere in your implementation, though).

Now, within your "`keyDown`" implementation, to look for the <kbd>command</kbd> key, "`NSEvent`" objects respond to the ["`modifierFlags`" method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/modifierFlags) and one of the flags is "`NSCommandKeyMask`".

E.G.:

```
NSUInteger flags = [theEvent modifierFlags];
if( flags == NSCommandKeyMask ){
    // Got it!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! So I cannot directly within my AppDelegate catch key events? I have to absolutely subclass WebView? I guess if not keystrokes won't get caught within the WebView. I'm a bit rusty with the XCode dev but I'll check out how to subclass again and I'll follow your instructions. Thanks again! Very appreciated :)

Comment: The Application Delegate doesn't descend nor does it receive any NSResponder methods, so the proper place to catch key down events is the currently-in-focus view where the NSResponder action happens. Let me know if your subclassing is a success!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Now I've gotta find how to call back to the AppDelegate to tell to hide/show the other webviews. Any idea about this? I need to control the other webviews' visibility. Thanks again!

Comment: this is a separate (and new) question, but maybe you could have your other subclassed WebViews listening for NSNotifications that you create to hide and show themselves.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm now lost again hehe. I'll go check the docs about NSNotifications. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about what kind of views they are. 
Put each one inside a tab of an NSTabView, with or without tab control displayed.

With tab control, set the desired key combo per tab in IB.

With or without it, create a menu item in a menu in the menu bar for each tab with the same key combos. This is the recommended way since long ago. Apple recommends adding a menu bar menu item for everything that has a keyboard shortcut. The menu bar will receive the keys before anything else.